# How can I sort results by price with 'AmazonECS.class.php'?

Tags: php, amazon-product-api

I am trying to use the `simplesearch.php` example to sort results from [Amazon's Product Advertising API (formerly ECS)](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/Welcome.html) in order of price.

I have the functions page and `sortParam` which should allow me if I have a clue at all to set the variables `$page` & `$sort` when I search and it sort them accordingly!

Have I got this wrong?

`search.php`:

```
require_once 'AmazonECS.class.php';
$client = new AmazonECS('', '', 'COM', 'htoshon-20');

$response  = $client->category($category1)->search($query);
```

`AmazonECS.class.php` - you can see by the commented out sections that I have tried to 
bypass!

```
    <?php
/**
 * Amazon ECS Class
 * http://www.amazon.com
 * =====================
 *
 * This class fetchs productinformation via the Product Advertising API by Amazon (formerly ECS).
 * It supports three basic operations: ItemSearch, ItemLookup and BrowseNodeLookup.
 * These operations could be expanded with extra prarmeters to specialize the query.
 *
 * Requirement is the PHP extension SOAP.
 *
 * @package      AmazonECS
 * @license      http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.txt GPL
 * @version      1.3.2
 * @author       Exeu <exeu65@googlemail.com>
 * @contributor  Julien Chaumond <chaumond@gmail.com>
 * @link         http://github.com/Exeu/Amazon-ECS-PHP-Library/wiki Wiki
 * @link         http://github.com/Exeu/Amazon-ECS-PHP-Library Source
 */
class AmazonECS
{
  const RETURN_TYPE_ARRAY  = 1;
  const RETURN_TYPE_OBJECT = 2;

  /**
   * Baseconfigurationstorage
   *
   * @var array
   */
  private $requestConfig = array();

  /**
   * Responseconfigurationstorage
   *
   * @var array
   */
  private $responseConfig = array(
    'returnType'          => self::RETURN_TYPE_OBJECT,
    'responseGroup'       => 'Medium',
    //'pageSize'            => '20',
    //'ItemPage' => '4',
    'optionalParameters'  => array()
  );

  /**
   * All possible locations
   *
   * @var array
   */
  private $possibleLocations = array('de', 'com', 'co.uk', 'ca', 'fr', 'co.jp', 'it', 'cn', 'es');

  /**
   * The WSDL File
   *
   * @var string
   */
  protected $webserviceWsdl = 'http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/AWSECommerceService.wsdl';

  /**
   * The SOAP Endpoint
   *
   * @var string
   */
  protected $webserviceEndpoint = 'https://webservices.amazon.%%COUNTRY%%/onca/soap?Service=AWSECommerceService';

  /**
   * @param string $accessKey
   * @param string $secretKey
   * @param string $country
   * @param string $associateTag
   */
  public function __construct($accessKey, $secretKey, $country, $associateTag)
  {
    if (empty($accessKey) || empty($secretKey))
    {
      throw new Exception('No Access Key or Secret Key has been set');
    }

    $this->requestConfig['accessKey']     = $accessKey;
    $this->requestConfig['secretKey']     = $secretKey;
    $this->requestConfig['associateTag']  = $associateTag;
    $this->country($country);
  }

  /**
   * execute search
   *
   * @param string $pattern
   *
   * @return array|object return type depends on setting
   *
   * @see returnType()
   */
  public function search($pattern, $nodeId = null)
  {
    if (false === isset($this->requestConfig['category']))
    {
      throw new Exception('No Category given: Please set it up before');
    }

    $browseNode = array();
    if (null !== $nodeId && true === $this->validateNodeId($nodeId))
    {
      $browseNode = array('BrowseNode' => $nodeId);
    }

    $params = $this->buildRequestParams('ItemSearch', array_merge(
      array(
        'Keywords' => $pattern,
        'SearchIndex' => $this->requestConfig['category']
      ),
      $browseNode
    ));

    return $this->returnData(
      $this->performSoapRequest("ItemSearch", $params)
    );
  }

  public function lookup($asin)
  {
    $params = $this->buildRequestParams('ItemLookup', array(
      'ItemId' => $asin,
    ));

    return $this->returnData(
      $this->performSoapRequest("ItemLookup", $params)
    );
  }

  /**
   * Implementation of BrowseNodeLookup
   * This allows to fetch information about nodes (children anchestors, etc.)
   *
   * @param integer $nodeId
   */
  public function browseNodeLookup($nodeId)
  {
    $this->validateNodeId($nodeId);

    $params = $this->buildRequestParams('BrowseNodeLookup', array(
      'BrowseNodeId' => $nodeId
    ));

    return $this->returnData(
      $this->performSoapRequest("BrowseNodeLookup", $params)
    );
  }

  /**
   * Implementation of SimilarityLookup
   * This allows to fetch information about product related to the parameter product
   *
   * @param string $asin
   */
  public function similarityLookup($asin)
  {
    $params = $this->buildRequestParams('SimilarityLookup', array(
      'ItemId' => $asin
    ));

    return $this->returnData(
      $this->performSoapRequest("SimilarityLookup", $params)
    );
  }

  /**
   * Builds the request parameters
   *
   * @param string $function
   * @param array  $params
   *
   * @return array
   */
  protected function buildRequestParams($function, array $params)
  {
    $associateTag = array();

    if(false === empty($this->requestConfig['associateTag']))
    {
      $associateTag = array('AssociateTag' => $this->requestConfig['associateTag']);
    }

    return array_merge(
      $associateTag,
      array(
        'AWSAccessKeyId' => $this->requestConfig['accessKey'],
        'Request' => array_merge(
          array('Operation' => $function),
          $params,
          $this->responseConfig['optionalParameters'],
          array('ResponseGroup' => $this->prepareResponseGroup())
    )));
  }

  /**
   * Prepares the responsegroups and returns them as array
   *
   * @return array|prepared responsegroups
   */
  protected function prepareResponseGroup()
  {
    if (false === strstr($this->responseConfig['responseGroup'], ','))
      return $this->responseConfig['responseGroup'];

    return explode(',', $this->responseConfig['responseGroup']);
  }

  /**
   * @param string $function Name of the function which should be called
   * @param array $params Requestparameters 'ParameterName' => 'ParameterValue'
   *
   * @return array The response as an array with stdClass objects
   */
  protected function performSoapRequest($function, $params)
  {
    $soapClient = new SoapClient(
      $this->webserviceWsdl,
      array('exceptions' => 1)
    );

    $soapClient->__setLocation(str_replace(
      '%%COUNTRY%%',
      $this->responseConfig['country'],
      $this->webserviceEndpoint
    ));

    $soapClient->__setSoapHeaders($this->buildSoapHeader($function));

    return $soapClient->__soapCall($function, array($params));
  }

  /**
   * Provides some necessary soap headers
   *
   * @param string $function
   *
   * @return array Each element is a concrete SoapHeader object
   */
  protected function buildSoapHeader($function)
  {
    $timeStamp = $this->getTimestamp();
    $signature = $this->buildSignature($function . $timeStamp);

    return array(
      new SoapHeader(
        'http://security.amazonaws.com/doc/2007-01-01/',
        'AWSAccessKeyId',
        $this->requestConfig['accessKey']
      ),
      new SoapHeader(
        'http://security.amazonaws.com/doc/2007-01-01/',
        'Timestamp',
        $timeStamp
      ),
      new SoapHeader(
        'http://security.amazonaws.com/doc/2007-01-01/',
        'Signature',
        $signature
      )
    );
  }

  /**
   * provides current gm date
   *
   * primary needed for the signature
   *
   * @return string
   */
  final protected function getTimestamp()
  {
    return gmdate("Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z");
  }

  /**
   * provides the signature
   *
   * @return string
   */
  final protected function buildSignature($request)
  {
    return base64_encode(hash_hmac("sha256", $request, $this->requestConfig['secretKey'], true));
  }

  /**
   * Basic validation of the nodeId
   *
   * @param integer $nodeId
   *
   * @return boolean
   */
  final protected function validateNodeId($nodeId)
  {
    if (false === is_numeric($nodeId) && $nodeId <= 0)
    {
      throw new InvalidArgumentException(sprintf('Node has to be a positive Integer.'));
    }

    return true;
  }

  /**
   * Returns the response either as Array or Array/Object
   *
   * @param object $object
   *
   * @return mixed
   */
  protected function returnData($object)
  {
    switch ($this->responseConfig['returnType'])
    {
      case self::RETURN_TYPE_OBJECT:
        return $object;
      break;

      case self::RETURN_TYPE_ARRAY:
        return $this->objectToArray($object);
      break;

      default:
        throw new InvalidArgumentException(sprintf(
          "Unknwon return type %s", $this->responseConfig['returnType']
        ));
      break;
    }
  }

  /**
   * Transforms the responseobject to an array
   *
   * @param object $object
   *
   * @return array An arrayrepresentation of the given object
   */
  protected function objectToArray($object)
  {
    $out = array();
    foreach ($object as $key => $value)
    {
      switch (true)
      {
        case is_object($value):
          $out[$key] = $this->objectToArray($value);
        break;

        case is_array($value):
          $out[$key] = $this->objectToArray($value);
        break;

        default:
          $out[$key] = $value;
        break;
      }
    }

    return $out;
  }

  /**
   * set or get optional parameters
   *
   * if the argument params is null it will reutrn the current parameters,
   * otherwise it will set the params and return itself.
   *
   * @param array $params the optional parameters
   *
   * @return array|AmazonECS depends on params argument
   */
  public function optionalParameters($params = null)
  {
    if (null === $params)
    {
      return $this->responseConfig['optionalParameters'];
    }

    if (false === is_array($params))
    {
      throw new InvalidArgumentException(sprintf(
        "%s is no valid parameter: Use an array with Key => Value Pairs", $params
      ));
    }

    $this->responseConfig['optionalParameters'] = $params;

    return $this;
  }

  /**
   * Set or get the country
   *
   * if the country argument is null it will return the current
   * country, otherwise it will set the country and return itself.
   *
   * @param string|null $country
   *
   * @return string|AmazonECS depends on country argument
   */
  public function country($country = null)
  {
    if (null === $country)
    {
      return $this->responseConfig['country'];
    }

    if (false === in_array(strtolower($country), $this->possibleLocations))
    {
      throw new InvalidArgumentException(sprintf(
        "Invalid Country-Code: %s! Possible Country-Codes: %s",
        $country,
        implode(', ', $this->possibleLocations)
      ));
    }

    $this->responseConfig['country'] = strtolower($country);

    return $this;
  }

  public function category($category = null)
  {
    if (null === $category)
    {
      return isset($this->requestConfig['category']) ? $this->requestConfig['category'] : null;
    }

    $this->requestConfig['category'] = $category;

    return $this;
  }

  public function responseGroup($responseGroup = null)
  {
    if (null === $responseGroup)
    {
      return $this->responseConfig['responseGroup'];
    }

    $this->responseConfig['responseGroup'] = $responseGroup;

    return $this;
  }

  public function returnType($type = null)
  {
    if (null === $type)
    {
      return $this->responseConfig['returnType'];
    }

    $this->responseConfig['returnType'] = $type;

    return $this;
  }

  /**
   * Setter/Getter of the AssociateTag.
   * This could be used for late bindings of this attribute
   *
   * @param string $associateTag
   *
   * @return string|AmazonECS depends on associateTag argument
   */
  public function associateTag($associateTag = null)
  {
    if (null === $associateTag)
    {
      return $this->requestConfig['associateTag'];
    }

    $this->requestConfig['associateTag'] = $associateTag;

    return $this;
  }

  /**
   * @deprecated use returnType() instead
   */
  public function setReturnType($type)
  {
    return $this->returnType($type);
  }

  /**
   * Setting the resultpage to a specified value.
   * Allows to browse resultsets which have more than one page, but cannot exceed 10 pages.
   *
   * @param integer $page
   *
   * @return AmazonECS
   */
  // public function page($page)
  // {
    // if (false === is_numeric($page) || $page <= 0 || $page > 10)
    // {
      // throw new InvalidArgumentException(sprintf(
        // '%s is an invalid page value. It has to be numeric and positive and less than 10',
        // $page
      // ));
    // }

    // $this->responseConfig['optionalParameters'] = array_merge(
      // $this->responseConfig['optionalParameters'],
      // array("ItemPage" => $page)
    // );

    // return $this;
  // }

  /**
   *Specifying how the response message should be sorted
   *@param string $sort
   *
   *@return AmazonECS
   */
  public function sortParam($sort)
  {
    if (false == is_string($sort))
    {
        throw new InvalidArgumentException(sprintf(
          '%s is not a valid sorting parameter, it has to be a valid string',
          $sort
          ));
    }

    $this->responseConfig['optionalParameters'] = array_merge(
        $this->responseConfig['optionalParameters'],
        array("Sort" => $sort)
        );

    return $this;
  }
}
```

Ops added wrong code above --corrected now
Thanks for any help

Carl

Comment: Why are you bypassing parts of Amazon's class? What's not working?

Comment: Hi -- I cant display the next page of results or sort by price in the list! I have the functions added but I don't get how I use them like the sortParam($sort) which I though all I had to do was set the $sort to say +price etc when I send the request to get the results. And same with $page to display second page of results! But I cant seem to get the optionalParameters to work!

Comment: I think you can't sort results when searching ALL? but when I sub cat say DVD is set it should work
If i add this in here I can get the second page but only if i set it to a number not a variable?
<code>$params = $this->buildRequestParams('ItemSearch', array_merge(
      array(
        'Keywords' => $pattern,
        'SearchIndex' => $this->requestConfig['category'],
  //'ItemPage' => $this->requestConfig['page'],
  'nr_pages'     => '10',
  'MerchantId'    => 'All',
  'Condition'     => 'All',
  'Availability'    => 'Available'
  'ItemPage'      => '2'
      ),
      $browseNode
    ))</code>